# How to call django custom command from code? call_command() doesn't work

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a telegram bot which uploads images to a django website. You send to the bot a picture -> bot uploads the picture to the server and adds info to the model -> picture appears on the webpage

I'm stuck with the "bot adds the info to the model" part.
Basically, what I want to do is to use the django.core.management.call_command to call a custom command from code which adds info.

Here is the structure

```
website/
    bot.py
    manage.py
    myapp/
        __init__.py
        management/
            __init__.py
            commands/
                __init__.py
                myapp_task.py
        views.py
```

Here is my custom command

```
# myapp_task.py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from picfeed.models import Captions

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Adds captions to the model'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('cap_text', type=str)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        cap_text = options['cap_text']
        caption = Captions(cap_text = cap_text)
        caption.save()
        self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('Successfully added caption "%s"' % cap_text))
```

When I use Terminal and `python manage.py myapp_task 'some string to add to the model'` works just perfectly fine.

However, when I call myapp_task from the code it doesn't work:

```
#bot.py
from django.core.management import call_command

call_command('myapp_task',cap_text = 'Hello there!' )
```

The error:

```
 \website>python bot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\EgOl7001\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 103, in call_command
    app_name = get_commands()[command_name]
KeyError: 'myapp_task'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 3, in <module>
    call_command('myapp_task',cap_text = 'Hello there!' )
  File "C:\Users\EgOl7001\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 105, in call_command
    raise CommandError("Unknown command: %r" % command_name)
django.core.management.base.CommandError: Unknown command: 'myapp_task'
```

I would appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use all django toolbox without setting your configuration.

You should try to add, in your `bot.py` something like that before using django:

```
import os
import django
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "website.settings")
django.setup()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage